# Detect user is from europe or usa

Tags: android, location

Is there any fast and stable way to detect whether a user is from USA, Asia, or Europe?

I want to show ads in my app, so I need it.

Thanks

Comment: how about some context for your app? the answer to this question probably depends on the usage case...

Comment: The phone has a GPS, right?  Doesn't the ad already filter based on location?

Comment: It depends on which ad network you're using, if you want to filter them using the available server-side tools of the engine (if any). However, since you've tagged it only as `android`, it raises the doubts if you're just trying something custom in Android only. In that case, we'll be left to guess as what you're trying to do, since by "detect user is from X" can differ according to your definition of "from" in this particular case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Option 1**

```
//Returns the ISO country code equivalent of the current 
//registered operator's MCC (Mobile Country Code).
  android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso()
```

**Option 2**

```
//Returns a constant indicating the device phone type.
android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getPhoneType()
```

**Option 3**

```
//Returns the name of this locale's country, localized to locale.
context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getDisplayCountry(Locale locale);
```

First two, rely on the network or phone type. The third one relies on the configuration of the phone, assuming that even if someone from the USA is in Europe, will still have the phone setup to be from USA, other ways it should just be treated as european.

By the way, USA is a country, Europe and Asia are continents, you're probably referring to America instead, or North America in any case.

That is, assuming you don't want GPS to avoid devices without it

Comment: No , I mean continents ,  I think option 1 is possible

Comment: good code but how do i actually use it to get all countries european and do and   if else statement?